# How to merge two same rows by and display different id rows in codeiginter mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

my table like this

```
 id ,  user_id , product_id , product_name , sub_name , status
  1 ,     1    ,    001     ,    name1     ,  sub1,       1
  2 ,     1    ,    001     ,    name1     ,  sub2,       1
  3 ,     1    ,    002     ,    name2     ,  sub3,       1
```

i want to display my result in my view page like

```
 id , user_id , product_id , product_name , sub_name , status
  1 ,  1      ,  001     ,    name1     ,  sub1,       1
  3 ,  1      ,  002     ,    name2     ,  sub3,       1
```

My Sql Query

```
$data['product'] = $this->db->group_by('product_id')
            ->where(array('user_id' => $id, 'product_id' => $product_id))->get('sr_shortserials')->result();
```

But i got like this

```
 id , user_id , product_id , product_name , sub_name , status
  3 ,  1      ,  002     ,    name2     ,  sub3,       1
```

this one ok but i want both id 1 and 3

Comment: Are you getting the row id: 2 instead of id: 3 now? Please update your question with the current output.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to display all products from the table with the earliest sub_name field value.

The best way would be to restructure your data and spin the sub_name field off to its separate table because your current data strcuture is not too high on the normal form ladder.

But the main logic of the query is no really dependent on whether the sub_name is a different table or not. You need to obtain the minimum id per product (min sub_name id if sub_names are in different table) and join in back to the main table (separate sub_names table) to get the details right.

```
select t1.*
from yourtable t1
inner join 
     (select user_id, product_id, min(id) as minid
      from yourtable
      group by user_id, product_id) t2 on t1.id=t2.minid
```

Comment: no i want to display product id without same(if i have 001 four times and 002 one time  in table means the 001 id should display one time and 002 also want to display)

Comment: I got this, but you need to determine which sub_name you present in the output. Mysql will not be able to figure it out for you.

Comment: thats not a matter , you dont consider that, Just consider id and project_id

Comment: It's still the same decision. You need to decide which id to include.

Comment: i have only one table but u explained with two tables

Comment: I wrote that you should have 2 tables, not one, but the logic is the same with both approaches. The sample code I gave you uses 1 table, not 2. The subquery runs on the same table as the main query.

Comment: okay but i use codeiginiter, ok i will try and accept your answer , Thank you so much